# how to use datetime-local in input field in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using datetime-local in input field but if i use that my form was not valid so in this case what should i do?
`<input class="form-control pmd-z-depth-1 shadow-demo" id="updateend_date" type="date" name="end_date">`

**Output**
`2018-01-01T01:00`

**Expected Output**
`2018-01-01T01:00Z`